¿Como puedo darle estilo personalizados (css) a elementos dentro de un bucle for?, Tambien me pasa con los FormModel de Django
Mi Html: El problema es que no me quiere acceder a los valores del diccionario de grupo_estilos, para ser mas exacto no me accede a el valor de la clave 'Agua' y es lo mismo con las otras claves 'Aceite', 'Luz'...etc, es decir que de 'Agua.bg_class' me devuelda un vacio y lo mismo con el 'text' e 'imagen'. Tengo entendido que las plantillas de django no adminten o no soportan trabajar con diccionarios, pero es por esos que cree un filtro que permite acceder a los diccionarios desde la plantilla, bueno ademas de este problema quisiera saber como es que se trabaja con estilos en un bucle for y con los ForModel de django, y como hago este problema de la plantilla que no me deja acceder a los valores de mi diccionario
Mi filtro:
@register.filter(name='diccionario')
def get_item(dictionary, key):
if isinstance(dictionary, dict):
    return mark_safe(dictionary.get(key, ""))
return ""

Mi html:
{% extends 'ficha/base.html' %}
{% load filtros_personales %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}


 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'ficha/css/inicio.css '%}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/01e154aaee.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- {% block titulo %}INICIO{% endblock %} -->
    </head>
    <h1>Panel de Control</h1>

    <section class="section content-box">
        <h3 class="title-databox">Tablero Panel de Control</h3>
        {% for grupo in grupos %}
            {% if grupo.nombre in grupo_estilos %}
                {% with grupo_estilos|diccionario:grupo.nombre as value %}
                    <div class="data-box {{ value.bg_class }}">
                        <div class="inside-text">
                            <h3>150</h3>
                            <p>{{ value.texto|safe }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon">
                            <img src="{% static value.imagen %}" alt="{{ grupo.nombre }}" class="img-icon">
                        </div>
                        <a href="{% url 'ficha:inicio_grupos' grupo.id %}" class="info">
                            Más info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                {% endwith %}
            {% else %}
                <p>No se encontró estilo para el grupo: {{ grupo.nombre }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </section>
    

    <section class="content-chart">
        <h3>Joven por Tribu</h3>
        <canvas id="my-chart"> </canvas>
        <div id="labels-container" style="margin-left: 20px;">
            <!-- Aquí se agregarán los labels -->
        </div>
    </section>
{% endblock %}

Mi vista:
def inicio(request, grupoespiritual_id=None): 

perfil = request.user.perfilusuario
grupoespiritual = GrupoEspiritual.objects.all()

grupo_estilos = {
    "Agua": {
        "bg_class": "bg-agua",
        "texto": "Jóvenes en el Grupo <br>Agua",
        "imagen": "ficha/image/gotas.png",
    },
    "Aceite": {
        "bg_class": "bg-aceite",
        "texto": "Jóvenes en el Grupo <br>Aceite",
        "imagen": "ficha/image/petroleo.png",
    },
    "Sal": {
        "bg_class": "bg-sal",
        "texto": "Jóvenes en el Grupo <br>Sal",
        "imagen": "ficha/image/salFB.png",
    },
    "Luz": {
        "bg_class": "bg-luz",
        "texto": "Jóvenes en el Grupo <br>Luz",
        "imagen": "ficha/image/luz-de-tungsteno.png",
    },
    "Altar": {
        "bg_class": "bg-altar",
        "texto": "Jóvenes que desean <br>Servir en el Altar",
        "imagen": "ficha/image/altar.png",
    },
    "Registrado": {
        "bg_class": "bg-agregado",
        "texto": "Jóvenes <br>Registrados",
        "imagen": "ficha/image/addJoven.png",
    },
    "Apartados": {
        "bg_class": "bg-apartado",
        "texto": "Jóvenes <br>Apartados",
        "imagen": "ficha/image/removeJoven.png",
    },
    "Iglesias": {
        "bg_class": "bg-iglesias",
        "texto": "Iglesias <br>Registradas",
        "imagen": "ficha/image/iglesia.png",
    },
    # Añada mas grupos aqui si es necesario
}

# print(f'Este es el dict: {grupo_estilos}')Depuracion
if perfil.es_encargado_nacional:
    
    if grupoespiritual_id:
        g_espiritual = GrupoEspiritual.objects.get(id=grupoespiritual_id)
        jovenes = FichaJoven.objects.filter(grupoespiritual=g_espiritual)
        return render(request, 'ficha/panels/jovenes.html', {'grupos': grupoespiritual, 'jovenes': jovenes, 'grupo_estilos': grupo_estilos})
    else:
        return render(request, 'ficha/panels/inicio.html', {'grupos': grupoespiritual, 'grupo_estilos': grupo_estilos})
    
elif perfil.es_asistente or perfil.es_encargado:
    if grupoespiritual_id:
        g_espiritual = GrupoEspiritual.objects.get(id=grupoespiritual_id)
        jovenes = FichaJoven.objects.filter(grupoespiritual=g_espiritual, departamento=perfil.departamento)
        return render(request, 'ficha/panels/jovenes.html', {'grupos': grupoespiritual, 'jovenes': jovenes, 'grupo_estilos': grupo_estilos})
    else:
        return render(request, 'ficha/panels/inicio.html', {'grupos': grupoespiritual, 'grupo_estilos': grupo_estilos})
return render(request, 'ficha/panels/inicio.html', {'grupos': grupoespiritual, 'grupo_estilos': grupo_estilos})

